# Retrieving Cell Value in Silverlight Datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to get a value from a cell in my datagrid, the code below returns the value from the cell as "System.Windows.Controls.Textblock" whereas I would like the actual value from the cell. The column I am trying to work with is ID in the code.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="245" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,77,0,0" Name="dataIssue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512">
  <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID"/>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=subject}" Header="Subject"/>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=project_ID}" Header="Project ID"/>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=elapsed}" Header="Time"/>
  </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>


public void StartTimer(object o, RoutedEventArgs sender)
{
   if ((string)timeButton.Content == "Start")
   {

     string getID = dataIssue.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dataIssue.SelectedItem).ToString();
     child.GetID = getID;
     watch.Start();
     timeButton.Content = "Stop";
   }
}
```

Comment: > This class is accessible or XAML-usable only through DataGrid styles and templates.
(c) MSDN about DataGridCell

Comment: Oh, the class is for the Button_Click I just forgot to include that lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this...

```
 TextBlock txtBlock=(TextBlock) myGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(myGrid.SelectedItem);

string retrivingtext = txtBlock.Text;
```

Here `myGrid=GridName:`

**TextBlock= Type of column like**