# How to cast value from datagrid to int?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I must read a datagrid column as a int type. My variable id is int and i past from data base to that column int. This is my code but i have an error:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(DataGrid.Columns[0].ToString());
```

And this is error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Any solution?

Comment: Because the string value is not equivalent to an integer. The error is pretty clear.

Comment: ok and how i can cast it to int

Comment: What you are getting is `Column Name` not Column Index

Comment: `DataGrid.Columns[0].ToString()` will return something like `DataGridColumn` that is not a valid `Int32`. To access the cell's value you should probably use the `GetCellContent` DataGridColumn method as it is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187734/retrieving-cell-value-in-silverlight-datagrid.

Comment: have you tried `int columnIndex = myGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex`

Comment: You could easily work this out yourself if you just did something like `var t = DataGrid.Columns[0].ToString()` and put a break-point on that line. You'd then see what value `t` had, and whether it is suitable for converting to an `int`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you choose a wrong way.

First: you try to convert DataGridColumn string representation to int - i.e. you try to cast string like "System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn" (if DataGridColumn not overloads ToString() method) to integer.

Second: your datagrid likely binded to some collection and the proper way is to access this collection and retreive needed values.